# Crash when i add getActivity() to retrieve data from firestore in Fragment

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

When I need the context inside my fragment, I don't use getActivity() in firestore method, but **Sometimes** firestore code crash and give me NullPointer. ..to fix it, I try use:

```
.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new Event..)
```

when i add that `getActivity()`, like example below, it **Always** NullPointer

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextView demand;
    private TextView design;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        demand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_production_demand_text_count);
        design = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_production_design_text_count);


        return view;
    }

    // @Override
    // public void onAttach(Context context) {
    //     super.onAttach(context);
    // }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            // retrieve likes count
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Demand").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                        int count = documentSnapshots.size(); // count id

                        demand.setText(count);

                    }
                }
            });

            // retrieve likes count
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Design").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                        int count = documentSnapshots.size(); // count id

                        design.setText(count);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

when i use `getActivity()` this fragment always crash, when i don't use `getActivity()` sometime crash 
how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have your error and stacktrace output?  Can you put that in your question? - My guess is that the problem is in `getActivity()`, but you don't show us the definition of that method, so how can we know?

Comment: thanks for your respond. i cannot get stacktrace, any solution? @Steve

Comment: i put the code inside onStart in Fragment.class @Steve

Comment: I want to see what getActivity() does.  I still don't see that code in your question.  You say you "add that conditional", and yet that code does not appear anywhere.  What does is something similar, that involves calling getActivity().  You say that when you add that code, you always get a NullPointer exception.  So it seems likely to me that that exception is being thrown by getActivity().

Comment: it Always crash when i add `addSnaphotListener(getActivity(), new Event)` and sometime crash when no `getActivity()` , like this `addSnaphotListener(new Event....)`  i Just edit my question, previous question wrong, sorry about that @Steve

Comment: but you're not going to show me what getActivity() is, eh?

Comment: i don't even not knowing what getActivity does? i Just put complete code it might be show you what getActivity()..

Comment: Ok.  Well, without that or a stack trace, I have no fresh ideas.  Someone who knows this technology more intimately might know what's going on from what you provide, but not me.